# Error whilst sending an email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, html-email

I am trying to send email using c# following is my code.

```
try
{
    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    msg.From = new MailAddress("kmrizwan.shahid@gmail.com");
    msg.To.Add("kmrizwan.shahid@gmail.com");//Text Box for To Address  
    msg.Subject = "Testinng subject"; //Text Box for subject  
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
    msg.Body = "testing comment is here..";//Text Box for body  
    msg.Priority = MailPriority.High;

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("kmrizwan.shahid@gmail.com", "");
    client.Port = 587;
    client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    client.EnableSsl = true;

    object userstate = msg;     
    client.Send(msg);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Giving following exception
[image]

Comment: There is no point in catching an exception if you're just going to throw it again.

Comment: Make sure the port is not blocked by firewall(s)

Comment: @Erno i have already turn off the firewall.

Comment: Having two step auth on your gmail account could cause this too

Comment: @DanielElliott I was having another one code which was working fine but that code is also throwing same exception

Comment: instead of ("smtp.gmail.com", 587) try to use your ISP's  smtp service.

Comment: Possible solution here http://forums.asp.net/t/1073943.aspx/1

Comment: I assume you're not actually running this code with an empty password?

Comment: yes i just remove it from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's common for internet providers to block the port used by SMTP, except to their own outgoing mailserver. The reason is to prevent spamming.

If that is the case for you, you need to use the mail server of your internet provider instead of the GMail server.

Comment: A simple telnet test to port 25 will confirm this.